# br clear="all" vs css solution

Tags: css

I have a div that is float:left, and after the div is the rest of the page.
In order to keep the rest of the page below the div, I must first place a

```
<br clear="all">
```

Q: How do I position the rest of the page below the floated div?
I think that I need to wrap the rest of the page in a new div and float it as well.
But I tend to stay away from floats as much as I can.

Comment: Can you fiddle it / post an example of what you mean?

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: In html5, the br tag does not have such attribute.

Comment: br with prop `clear: both` is the only way to clear AND keep the margin top intact on next element after floating vertical flow. However, one trick is to use pseudo on the clearing element. Example `<h2>Im a heading after floating stuff and usally I got 20px margin top</h2>` Then CSS: `h2:before { content: ""; display:table; margin-bottom: 20px; }` This is only good if the `<h2>` has no background styles or border top applied to it as the pseudo will then be incuded. But for simple divs and wrappers this works well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the next item you can use the style `clear:left`.

Another alternative is to set the `overflow` style on the parent of the floating element to make it contain it, like `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Make sure that if you use `overflow: hidden` that the element does not have an explicit height set (like `height: 200px`) doing so will potentially hide content from the user.

Answer (score 22):

after the div you've floated. add the following code.

```
<div style='clear:both'></div>
```

then continue the rest of the page as usual.

Comment: I used this a lot, but do not see why it is better than using the br tag instead. Also, VisualStudio does not flag an error if you make a (accidental) self-closing div, but I have had really spooky javascript misbehaviour on that. So this solution is a source for bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Create a class and insert into CSS:

```
br.cb { clear: both; }
```

Insert into HTML:

```
<br class="cb">
```

This made it past W3 markup and CSS validator.

Comment: +1 I need this in a lot of places, and it is much shorter, and clearer, than with a div tag, which is not self-closing.

Answer (score 3):

I usually wrap another div around the floating div, with style `overflow: auto`